# Can't use php variables defined in another file

Tags: javascript, php, require

I have three php files, one defines a constant, the other has the html markup and includes a php file wigh renders js content. the third is the php file rendering the js content. the code is as shown below.

the first file named "config.php" :

```
<?php

define('TESTVAR','test variable');
?>
```

the second file named "main.php" :

```
<?php
require_once ('config.php');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.php"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the third file named "script.php" :

```
alert(<?php echo TESTVAR ?>);
```

this is what gets loaded as script.php:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant TESTVAR - assumed 'TESTVAR' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\trials\testphpinjs\script.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
TESTVAR);
```

it's not that php is not being rendered, if i change the script.php to

```
alert(<?php echo '\'testing'. 'php' . 'echo\'' ?>);
```

it works perfectly and the loaded script can be viewed from developer tools as

```
alert('testingphpecho');
```

the only problem I have is that I cannot access the variables in pages required or included before

Comment: `script.php` is loaded by the browser, on its own. If you want to use the constant defined in `config.php`, you will need to require config.php from there as well.

Comment: You are already close to figuring it our yourself. Check at what point / in what request the `script.php` is loaded. Hint: not in the same request as `main.php`.

Comment: dammit, that was stupid of me. didn't see it since the actual project is a much bigger framework but when simplified it could really help, but thanks a lot. do you want to write it as a proper answer so that I can set as correct or do you want me to write one for future help?

Comment: @jaafarNasrallah I'm sure this has come up before, so it might be flagged as a duplicate, although I can't find a proper one at the moment. But this is not a "stupid" question as far as I'm concerned. Especially as it's part of a bigger framework, it can be easy to overlook something like this.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I'm not really new to stackoverflow, and i've looked well before posting. so thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.php"></script>`, the browser will issue a new request to load `script.php` directly. Since PHP is stateless, that request will not be handled in the same context as whatever processing goes on in `main.php`.

If you want to use the variables/constants defined in `config.php` within `script.php`, you will have to load it in there:

```
<?php require_once('config.php'); ?>
alert("<?php echo TESTVAR; ?>");
```

> Note that I've added quotation marks, since `TEST_VAR` is a string value in your example.

If your Javascript code relies on more than just `config.php` and its behavior depends on pre-processing that's done in `main.php`, it might be better to load it as an inline script instead:

```
<?php
require_once ('config.php');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php include('script.php'); ?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This way, PHP is loading the `script.php` file within the same context as `main.php`, and all constants and variables defined there will (should) be available for use by the code that's outputting your Javascript.